# Effect of changing ClickOnce application publish location on clients' machines

Tags: clickonce

OK, I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application published using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) to
`http://MyDevComputer1/DevPublishFolder/`, so the deployement link is `http://MyDevComputer1/DevPublishFolder/publish.htm`.

The application is already deployed to close to 20 machines in the company intranet. I now have a requirement to change the publish location to a different server in the same network, but I'm just not sure how this change will affect the users who already have the application installed on their client machines.

How do I make sure the application detects that the publish location has been changed to a different server during the next application start up on client machines?

Or must I go and uninstall the application on all the client machines, and then re-install from the new publish location?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Go to the Publish tab and click the Updates button.
- Add the new URL to Update Location dropdown list and click ok
- Publish

Once all of the clients have received the new version, they will look to the new URL (and your new server) for all future updates.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 It is in. Project Menu> (Project Name) Properties> Publish Tab> Updates...