# Click Once Migrate URL

Tags: clickonce

I have a Click Once App that has been published to the same location for a couple years, I now want to post an update to the program but want to migrate it to another url, is it a 2 step deployment?  I dont want to have to have the users change the url location and have 2 apps installed, is there a simple way to do this wothout getting into redirects and things of that sort?

Comment: What's wrong with a redirect from old URL to new URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the `Publish` page of your project options, and click on the `Updates` button. Change the `Update location` to the URI you want to publish to from now on. Publish one last version of your app to the original URI with those settings.

Now change the `Publish Location` back on the `Publish` tab to the same URI as your "update location" and publish the new version to the new location.

Any current users of your app will update to the next version from the original URI, and will now have an app that knows to look at the new location for the next version.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684794/effect-of-changing-click-once-application-publish-location-on-clients-machines

Comment: You're right - it looks like the question is a duplicate. I'll vote to close it.