# Is there a way to alter the update URL for installed click once applications

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

We have been using click once since 2006 and now have a need to change the update location, this happened once before but we just uninstalled and reinstalled, this will now be problematic.

A solution was presented in [Click Once Migrate URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711649/click-once-migrate-url), however when we tried this years ago (.NET 2.0), it failed with the app stating that the URL of the update and the URL of the client did not match raising a security risk and prevented the update from occurring and starting for that matter.

[The docs state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.updatelocation.aspx) that this property can only be altered in the application manifest, but I'm not sure the approach to actually change this in an already deployed app.

I want to use a process such as the following assuming current version is 5 and deployment location is apps.mycompany.com and new location is clickonce.mycompany.com

1. Publish app at clickonce.mycompany.com with version 5.2
2. Publish app at apps.mycompany.com with version 5.1 which has bootstrapping code when the app starts up to alter the apps manifest to change the URL.

With this process the clients will then get two new updates consecutively. Infect, if I publish 5.1 to both locations it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of thing can be solved by having the app uninstall itself, and then reinstall itself. I have done it before, although I was installing from a network location, and not a url, but it should be the same thing.

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx) on msdn for this solution. Go down to the section "How to programmatically uninstall a Click Once application and install a new version".

You can also check out a different version of the solution [here](http://isolvable.blogspot.com/2010/01/uninstalling-clickonce.html).

This works, but it's a bit tricky. It is the only way I know of to solve this type of problem though.

**EDIT** If you use the information in that article, here are 2 things to watch out for.

1. Make sure the update for the app that is uninstalling itself is not optional. You need to make the required version be the current deployed version. Otherwise, the restore option is available and is the default for the uninstall dialog box, and the app won't uninstall itself.
2. Make sure in the GetUninstallString method in the DeploymentUtils class, change the DisplayName it is looking for from "TestCertExp_CSharp" to the name of your app.

Comment: Sounds like a very interesting way of performing this operation. I do have one concern though, how does this process deal with stored user files and application settings? This is the main reason we do not wish to uninstall and reinstall as these are lost in the process. I suppose one option would be to have the upgrade process copy the resources to a temp location and have the new one read them back after the new version is installed?

Comment: Holly cow, that's a neat article and explains some updates to 3.5 SP-1 and 2.0 SP-1 I was not aware of. When we tried the change last time all clients were using 2.0 with XP, Vista wasn't even out at the time. Fortunately now everyones on Win-7 have .NET 4.0 and the app targets 3.5-SP1. I'm starting to think that due to these fixes that microsoft have included I might be able to quite simply issue an update with the new URI and be done with it. Thanks so much for your help, I'll be trying this with a test environment in the coming weeks.

Comment: There are some things to watch out for. See my answer for the update.

Answer (score 0):

use these command lines

```
mage.exe -Update setuptest_1_0_0_2.application -ProviderUrl http://127.0.0.1/setuptest/setuptest.application

mage.exe -Update setuptest_1_0_0_2.application -AppManifest setuptest_1_0_0_2\setuptest.exe.manifest

mage.exe -Sign setuptest_1_0_0_2.application -CertFile setuptest_TemporaryKey.pfx -Password mypassword

mage.exe -Update setuptest.application  -ProviderUrl http://127.0.0.1/setuptest/setuptest.application

mage.exe -Update setuptest.application -AppManifest setuptest_1_0_0_2\setuptest.exe.manifest

mage.exe -Sign setuptest.application -CertFile setuptest_TemporaryKey.pfx -Password mypassword
```

Check this: http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2939893&SiteID=1