# Changing ClickOnce locations breaks auto updates

Tags: vb.net, ftp, clickonce

We've recently changed servers and since the addresses are different we had to update the location information for our ClickOnce application. However after the change the previous version doesn't automatically detect that there's an update and wont update to the new version published on the new server.

The previous ClickOnce info was as follows

```
Publishing Folder Location: ftp://example.oldname.com/
Installation Folder URL:    http://www.name.com/dir/
Deployment web page:        appName.html
Version:                    1.0.0.0
```

Then it got changed to the following

```
Publishing Folder Location: ftp://name.ca/
Installation Folder URL:    http://www.name.com/newdir/ (also tried /dir/)
Deployment web page:        appName.html
Version:                    1.0.1.0
```

*Note: The application is set to check for updates before the application starts and was successfully updated on all versions <= 1.0.0.0 prior to the server change. So missing that setting isn't the issue.*

The application published to the new ftp server correctly. The installation folder url should point to the new ftp server correctly. Both `dir/` and `newdir/` were changed to point to the new location. Both `http://www.name.com/newdir/appName.htm` and `http://www.name.com/dir/appName.htm` opens up the right page.

All the files were copied from the old ftp to the new ftp. That includes the files for the application.

```
Application Files     - folder and it's contents
appName.htm           - file
AppName.application   - file
```

Both ftp servers are still running. The old one will be removed soon but it's still there for now.

After doing this the old application (v 1.0.0.0) isn't detecting and updating to the new version (1.0.1.0).

**Is this something that can be fixed or does the ClickOnce app require a new installation?**

Answer (score 0):

Requires new installation.

This is something you have to plan ahead on if you want to be able to automate it. We have done this before but first we produced a new update that would install the app from the new location and uninstall the currently running app. This is one of those times you actually put the "*cart before the horse*" so it takes planning.

Update:

Be aware that you cannot change the path on the local computer (where it gets its updates) because it will invalidate the security certificate and never attempt an update again.

Comment: That's what we're doing with our Android app but how would we do that with a ClickOnce app? It doesn't seem to give you the options to do what you suggest.

Comment: No, it doesn't do this for you, you have to write code to make it happen.

Comment: You might see if this post works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684794/effect-of-changing-clickonce-application-publish-location-on-clients-machines

Comment: Hmm, the solution in that link might work. I'll give it a try.